# How can I restore a db file in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongodb file, But I don't know what is exactly

And I want to browse it. I copied it on the mongodb databases path(C:\mongodb\bin\data\db) and ran mongod :

> mongod --dbpath C:\mongodb\bin\data\db

Then I tried to find it :

> show dbs

But there weren't my new db.

I tried to mongoimport. It started to work and continued for about 5 hours. But it didn't finish !!!

How can I browse this DB file ?

Comment: use robomongo
Its free user interface to go through mongo dbs.
https://robomongo.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you have created your snapshot. An alternative to mongoimport is [mongorestore](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/). If you have created a dump via **mongodump** this is the way how to restore it.

[mongoimport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoimport/) is used in combination with content from a JSON, CSV, or TSV file via mongoexport.

If that not helps some more information on how you have created your data file would be great.

Comment: It's my main problem. I didn't create it. I only received the file and I don't have access to the file creator. Are the any solution to find file type (file does not have any extensions)? 
And one more: When I tried to mongoimport, it starts to read file and i was seeing data in command prompt. But it didn't finish after 5 hours!